# Network Monitoring and Intrusion Protection Software

Tags: monitoring

I am trying to find out what is considered by security experts to be industry standard, or just highly regarded, intrusion detection software that also takes measures to prevent an attack whether it is shutting down the server or some other form of prevention.

I work for a small company of about 10 people. We don't have a dedicated IT guy, just a guy that comes by when he isn't at his full time job and we have really basic IT or Network admin needs. I am a web developer with some experience in IT and server administration, but definitely not enough that I would consider myself to be capable of filling an IT, Network Admin, or Security Admin role.

They don't want to hire a credentialed person to fill the role. The network was setup by a professional, so the firewalls are setup, and any unused and unneeded ports are shutdown. Really there isn't any external traffic coming so really just HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP for basic functionality. Website is hosted by a 3rd party. Windows Server 2012.

Anyway, what they envision is having this software that will block a network intrusion the second it happens, if it happens, and send out an alert to the "admins". Also, creates a log that can be monitored through a dashboard to see what traffic has come in from outside the network.

Thanks for the input on some reputable software to accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunately, product recommendations are off topic in security.SE - mostly because they get out of date too fast.  However, I'd suggest that what you're looking for is generally referred to as a magic bullet and you aren't likely to find something that will do all that.   Network Intrusion Detection Systems tend to be high on the false-positive rates - and that means that they eat time - people need to spend time on them.

Comment: Self-healing Intrusion Prevention Systems are still a long ways off. You are basically looking for a security analyst in a box (or a SOC in a box). We aren't there yet. I'm working on a project that would bring this closer to reality, but you are going to have to bring tools together to build something yourself that meets your needs, or get a managed security company to do all this for you.